# can't stop 4 threads run in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a Windows Form application with one Button to encode any file by using the encryption function:
public byte[] EncodeRc6fileFun (byte[] byteText)
(note: the input of EncodeRc6fileFun Methods is 16 byte[])
I Write a code C#
when clicking on button:

1. we select the file to be encrypted.
2. divide the file (that we select to be encrypted) into parts, the length of any of them is 16 byte
3. speed up the encryption process by using 4 Method of EncodeRc6fileFun that work in parallel to encrypt first four parts of the file together, then the next four parts, and so on until the file ends
4. we specify the name and location of the encrypted file

   ```
   private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

        string text;
        text = textBox4.Text;
        // Convert the text to a byte array
        byte[] MainKeynew1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        rc68 = new RC6(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text), MainKeynew1);        
        //Select file and divide it into parts
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a File";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            //Divide the file into parts of 16 bytes each 
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

            int partSize = 16; //16 bytes per part 

            List<byte[]> parts = new List<byte[]>();

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += partSize)
            {
                byte[] partBytes = bytes.Skip(i).Take(partSize).ToArray();

                parts.Add(partBytes);
            }

            //Encrypt the file in parallel using 4 methods of EncodeRc6File() 

            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }; //4 threads to run in parallel  

            Parallel.ForEach(parts, options, part => {
                byte[] encryptedPartBytes = rc68.EncodeRc6fileFun(part);

                //Save the encrypted part to a list  
                lock (parts)
                {
                    parts[parts.IndexOf(part)] = encryptedPartBytes;
                }
            });

            //Write the encrypted parts to a single file 

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string savePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

                using (var fs = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    foreach (var part in parts)
                    { fs.Write(part, 0, part.Length); }

                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
   ```

there is no error in code but its run too much then visual program break and throw exception:Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x10c6e28 to COM context 0x10c6d70 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.'

Comment: What does `rc68.EncodeRc6fileFun` look like? As an aside, I am not familiar with the RC6 algorithm, but no encryption algorithm that I am familiar with (RC4, AES) would allow this to work: each byte's encrypted value is (indirectly) a function of the input value _and_ the previous value, so you can't typically encrypt sections and concatenate them like you do here.

Comment: You might want to move the long running parallel operation to another thread for example using `await Task.Run(...)` to perform non-blocking operation.

Comment: when I use  rc68.EncodeRc6fileFun its work very good, but when I use 4 thread the problem appear

Comment: Yes, but your problem description suggests that the function is doing something other than just working with the bytes of the file, like trying to update the UI.